# LED ceiling fixture is super dim - why?

Tags: electrical, lighting, led

I'm stumped. I bought a Lutron Maestro MS-OPS2 occupancy switch and an LED light fixture for a closet when the old fixture's bulb burned out. Everything worked well for a couple of days, and then the light would be super dim when it came on:

[image: Dim light #1]

I thought the light had burned out, so I bought a different dimmable LED fixture and hooked it up, but it did the same thing. I assumed that the switch had died, so I bought a new switch and installed it, but the same thing happened. I replaced the light with a different fixture and the motion switch with a regular old light switch. The same thing happened:

[image: Dim light #2]

I removed the switch from the equation completely and wired the fixture directly to the non-switched romex - same result. My multimeter is reading 120 volts between hot and ground, and I've done and undone the wire nut connections a few times. What am I missing here? As best as I can tell, the only other things on this circuit are an outlet with nothing plugged into it, a vanity light and the vent fan in the bathroom - those all seem to work fine.  I feel like I'm going insane.

Comment: Does the motion sensor have a neutral wire?

Comment: No - the switch is connected via a switch loop.  Bypassing the switch completely doesn't have any effect, though.